# Adding zero width characters to strings

Tags: python

I want to add a zero width character to a string, so it visually looks like there's no space, but actually I can use the Python split function on the character to separate the string into "words".

I've searched around a lot, and apparently the equivalent of zero width space would be `\u200b`. However, if I write a string like `"Test\u200bTest"`, it gets printed as: `Test?Test`.

I also tried to add `.encode("utf-8")`. But that caused weird character additions to appear in the string. I suppose because the encoding is already set to UTF-8. Do I have to set the encoding to something else to get the output right?

Edit:

I'm actually working on a text encrypting program. As I don't want to give away where words end on first sight (to make manual decoding more difficult), I want to use an invisible char - as in the Zero width space.
As you can see
[here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
, the inserted question mark means that there's been an error trying to encode the `\u200b` char. Another indication for this:

```
teststr = "Test"+chr(8203)+"test"
file = open("C:\\...\\chartest.txt", "w")
file.write(teststr)
file.close()
```

This leads to the following error:
UnicodeEncodingError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 4: character maps to

This is possibly a console problem. Which is weird, though, as the console should have full unicode support. It shouldn't be necessary to do anything to add unicode characters. Besides: Changing to another code page (chcp 65001, chcp 1252) doesn't fix the problem (cp 65001 is even messing with Pythons traceback output, so better avoid it).

All in all I'm out of ideas. None of the mentioned characters are truly invisible. And the one which maybe would be invisible causes an EncodingError. Any ideas?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the string `"Test\u200bTest"`. My guess is that your terminal can't display the zero-width character and replaces it with a question mark.

Comment: This sounds like the XY problem - you don't need what you actually want. Can you clarify on wanting to split strings into words?

Comment: "Test"+chr(24)+"Test"

Comment: So you want an"invisible" char?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I need. An invisible character.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to solve what you need in a wrong way. How about instead you keep your string with normal spaces and whenever you need to print it without spaces, you just do

```
print(my_str.replace(' ', ''))
```

which will print your string without spaces (but keep my_str as it was)

Answer (score -1):

Try below :

```
str1 = "Test"

str1 = str1+chr(24)+str1
print (str1)
print(str1.split(chr(24)))
```

Comment: `Test?Test` actually it's an *up arrow* char but copy/paste messed it up.

Comment: Ascii Char 24 is equivalent to CANCEL character.

Comment: I know, I guess the shell decides how to represent it. In my case it's an up arrow char.

Comment: we can also use `chr(255)`

Comment: Replacing a well-defined Unicode character with random 8-bit characters whose semantics you apparently don't understand is not an improvement.